# How to make a conditional statement based on subsequent date time rows in R

Tags: r, time-series, conditional-statements

Suppose there is a data frame with two columns, number and time:

```
 data<-data.frame(number=c(1,5,3,6,7), 
                 datetime=c(as.POSIXct("2015/06/12 12:10:25"),
                            as.POSIXct("2015/06/12 12:10:27"),
                            as.POSIXct("2015/06/12 12:10:32"),
                            as.POSIXct("2015/06/12 12:10:33"),
                            as.POSIXct("2015/06/12 12:10:35")))

  number   datetime
1      1 2015/06/12 12:10:25
2      5 2015/06/12 12:10:27
3      3 2015/06/12 12:10:32
4      6 2015/06/12 12:10:33
5      7 2015/06/12 12:10:35
```

Conditions:

1) For row "N", consider all rows that datetime is less than the datetime at row "N" plus three seconds

2) Index=1: If one of the numbers in the selected rows is bigger than the number in row N, otherwise Index=0;

Output:

```
  number   datetime             Index
1      1 2015/06/12 12:10:25      1
2      5 2015/06/12 12:10:27      0
3      3 2015/06/12 12:10:32      1
4      6 2015/06/12 12:10:33      1
5      7 2015/06/12 12:10:36      0
```

I can do it using loops but I am pretty sure, it is not the optimized way in R.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way you can do it using `dplyr`.

Simply iterate through the dataframe rowwise and apply the logic in the `do` function:

```
library(dplyr)

data<-data.frame(number=c(1,5,3,6,7), 
                 datetime=c(as.POSIXct("2015/06/12 12:10:25"),
                            as.POSIXct("2015/06/12 12:10:27"),
                            as.POSIXct("2015/06/12 12:10:32"),
                            as.POSIXct("2015/06/12 12:10:33"),
                            as.POSIXct("2015/06/12 12:10:35")))

data %>% rowwise() %>%
    do(data.frame(
      number=.$number,
      datetime=.$datetime,
      Index=as.numeric(max(data[data$datetime < (.$datetime+3), c("number")]) > .$number)
    ))
```

The only part which is complicated might be the `Index` portion. Basically you go back to the data set `data` subset by the condition, and select the largest number (as this will guarantee that at least one of the numbers is larger than the current number if it exists). After that, the `as.numeric` will cast the boolean variable into 1, 0 as needed.

I have no idea why your example has a `NA`, and the number field changed from a 6 to a 7. Here is the output from the code above.

```
Source: local data frame [5 x 3]
Groups: <by row>

  number            datetime Index
1      1 2015-06-12 12:10:25     1
2      5 2015-06-12 12:10:27     0
3      3 2015-06-12 12:10:32     1
4      6 2015-06-12 12:10:33     1
5      7 2015-06-12 12:10:35     0
```

Comment: So basically you subset the data for each row. What if there are too many rows?

Comment: Then you probably need to rethink the representation of your problem. Is there a way to make the data set wider and shorter? Perhaps theres a way to subset your data first. This all depends on the problem at hand, and how many more rows is 'lots of rows'.